# how to insert next to a line

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file in this format

> machine name   host1
> something here1
>
> machine name   host1
> somethingelse2

I need to change this as

> machine name   host1
>
> set username 1000
>
> something here1
>
> machine name   host1
> set username 1001
>
> somethingelse2

I need find a line "machine name   host1" and insert line "set username with incremental-value"  on all occurrence next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v user=1000 '
  {print} 
  /machine name host1/ {printf("set username %d\n", user++)}
' filename
```

I pass the "seed" value for the user name with awk's -v option

Comment: Thanks for both the answers. but my requirement needs awk. :D

Answer (score 2):

Using a Perl one-liner (assuming the name of the file with the data is called 'machines':

```
perl -n -i.bak -e '$i=999 if !$i;
            if (m/machine name host1/) {
               $i++;
               $_ = "$_\nset username $i\n";
            };
            print;' machines
```

Note that the file itself will be changed and a backup file created with extension .bak

Comment: A one-liner with embedded newlines seems a bit of a misnomer. :)